# Should I add all my domain names to a single google apps account?

Tags: google-workspace, google-account

I have a large amount of domain names. I also have a Google Apps account (not a business one, but I'm grandfathered into having 50 users before I have to upgrade, etc.)

Since I'm no longer able to keep these domains up to date, I wanted to add them to my Google Apps account. However, some of these domain names are linked to other google usernames and it seems like I can't add them until I delete the other google user' connection. These other users are not necessarily Google Apps accounts/users, but things like Google webmaster tools, analytics, adsense or adwords.)

**So I wanted to know if this is a good idea to just add them all to one Google Apps account then delegate access via App's domain management?** As opposed to each domain having it's own Google Apps account? Especially since I want to delegate control of some of the sites to other people and give these people access to adsense revenue, analytics, etc.

One of the issues I have noticed already, is that my old Google Apps account's root domain name is not changeable; at least as far as I can tell. Is this something changeable if I upgrade to the paid google business apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on what kind of services you want enabled on the respective domains and what you need for each of them.

If you have 10 domains under your control, but 7 of them were registered to catch those spelling mistakes in accessing your main domain, then it would be good to add these 7 domains as an alias to your main domain in Google Apps.

As for the remaining 3 domains, lets say they were registered as special domain names for the different projects in your organization and not everyone in your organization is involved in that special project. If you don't require Google Sites for that domain, then you can just add the domain as another domain within your parent organization's Google Apps.

Like you said, adding all the domains into one Google Apps is good as it is a central area to control things, though it is subject to [certain limitations](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182081). You should have a separate Google Apps if you want to enjoy all the benefits that a primary domain has, for that special domain name that you might have.

Comment: +1 great answer. I'll leave the question unanswered for a day or so. When I have the time to read through the [certain limitations](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182081) **Also,** It may be worth a new question, but do you happen to know if there are any difference between the old >3yrs google Apps account (the free type like I have with 50 free users) and a new free account today?

Comment: Google rolls out new features to all Google Apps accounts, regardless of it's age. I believe the only difference is the user limit, and also you cannot create free accounts for Google Apps anymore, they recently removed it